# I've a file uploaded in SharePoint Library(Word file), and i would like to open the file in PDF directly from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've a file uploaded in SharePoint Library(Word file), and i would like to open the file in PDF directly from SharePoint and make some changes and save it so that it automatically gets updated in the SharePoint Library.Is there a way ??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to open the word with PDF directly from SharePoint document library?

There is no OOTB method to achieve your requirement.